# iPhone: How to prevent maximum screen brightness when charging?

Tags: iphone, charging, screen, display

I've set my screen brightness to about 50%. This works fine for me, except that the setting seems to be ignored when it's charging: then it's 100%. I've got a desktop charging stand on my bedside table, and this is exactly the place where I don't need maximum brightness!

**How can I make my iPhone respect the brightness setting even when charging?**

This is an iPhone 4 (iOS 4.1) but I noticed the same with the iPhone 3G (iOS 3.1.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to iOS 4.2. It fixes both the charging brightness and the locked screen brightness bugs. I just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to reproduce this issue. Is it possible that ambient light is increasing the brightness? Does it still go to 100% brightness if you turn off Auto-Brightness?

Comment: There is no ambient light :-) but I will turn off autobrightness and test tonight.

Comment: When Auto-Brightness is off, then the brightness is always as specified and not more. When Auto-Brightness is on, then it's much brighter but ONLY at the lock screen -- it dims down to ambient level once I slide to unlock. Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: @torben: I noticed the same thing, and it's very annoying that the lock screen is so bright, especially in a dark room. It only started happening in OS 4.x. I'm hoping it's a bug and not a feature...

Answer (score 1):

Can't fix it -- currently.

Based on postings so far, **this is a bug in iOS 4.1** (less prominent/problematic in 3.x versions).

The only solution would be to upgrade to a newer version **when** that becomes available **if** this bug has been fixed in that version.