# Prevent maximum screen brightness in lockscreen?

Tags: iphone, charging, display, screen-lock

I've set my screen brightness to about 50%. This works fine for me, except that the setting seems to be ignored while displaying the lockscreen while being charged: then it's 100%. I've got a desktop charging stand on my bedside table, and this is exactly the place where I don't need maximum brightness!

**How can I make my iPhone respect the brightness setting even when locked and charging?**

This is an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2.1. In an [earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/iphone-how-to-prevent-maximum-screen-brightness-when-charging), I asked about the brightness while charging - but this question is specifically about the *lockscreen brightness.*

It's already jailbroken so suggestions in that genre are fine too.

*Update:*
The auto-brightness setting is ON because I like that it dims at night but goes bright during the day; I have tried it OFF but I had to adjust the brightness manually too often during every day. I'm not aware of any jailbreak-specific setting regarding brightness.

Comment: In that *earlier question* you pointed it says it fixes the brightness on lockscreen too - and I don't experience this problem on my 4.3.3 neither do I remember such issue on 4.2 and I do pay attention to the brightness... So, maybe there's something wrong at your side?

Comment: @Cawas I'd not be surprised if there was *something wrong*, it wouldn't be the first time the phone acts up. I accepted the answer to that other because it did solve the brightness issue in general, but not in the lockscreen - that remains, hence this new question. I'd be willing to do some kind of total reset and blank reinstall, but this isn't Windows :-) so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I didn't mean it's necessarily a bug on the device... For instance, there is an **auto-brightness** setting that I leave **on** *and* with that sometimes the brightness change to adapt with local lights. If you got that off, then it should never change. From your last question, I noticed a comment where you payed attention to this, but you haven't specified anything about it here. And, this is just an instance. Since you've being toying with it, maybe there's another setting elsewhere, including on jailbroken apps you may have gotten.

Comment: I'll put that in the question too.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 4 and 5 were notorious for having this issue. They frequently ignored the ambient light sensor and were so stubborn, they refused to adjust the screen brightness to compensate. iOS 6 has corrected this issue.